# I need help debugging this error - Maths Quiz for Kids

Tags: swift, xcode

My school project is a children's maths game where it test them in addition, subtraction and multiplication. I have two VC's that are linked to the error. The error I keep having is that every time I choose any of the options it ignores all the other operations and follows the instructions for multiplication! I have tried everything and I'm getting frustrated with this application.

Option_VC

```
class Option_VC: UIViewController {

var addition_true: Bool = false
var subtract_true: Bool = false
var multiply_true: Bool = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if addition_true == true {
        let nextVC: Quiz_VC = segue.destinationViewController as! Quiz_VC
        nextVC.addition_true = true
    }else if subtract_true == true {
        let nextVC: Quiz_VC = segue.destinationViewController as! Quiz_VC
        nextVC.subtract_true = true
    }else {
        let nextVC: Quiz_VC = segue.destinationViewController as! Quiz_VC
        nextVC.multiply_true = true
    }
}

@IBAction func addition_enter(sender: AnyObject) {
    addition_true = true
    multiply_true = false
    subtract_true = false
}

@IBAction func subtract_enter(sender: AnyObject) {
    subtract_true = true
    addition_true = false
    multiply_true = false
}

@IBAction func multiply_enter(sender: AnyObject) {
    multiply_true = true
    addition_true = false
    subtract_true = false
}
```

}

Quiz_VC

```
class Quiz_VC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var n1_lbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var back: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var next: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var enter: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var answer_field: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var symbol_lbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var n2_lbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var comment_lbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var score_lbl: UILabel!
var addition_true: Bool = false
var subtract_true: Bool = false
var multiply_true: Bool = false
var enter_entered_true: Bool = false
var answer: UInt32 = 0
var finalanswer: UInt32 = 0
var n1: UInt32 = 0
var n2: UInt32 = 0
var count = 0
var score = 0
var temp: UInt32 = 0
var operation: String = ""


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    back.hidden = true
    next.hidden = true
    if addition_true == true {
        AdditionQuestions()
    }else if subtract_true == true {
        SubtractionQuestions()
    }
    if multiply_true == true && addition_true == false && subtract_true == false{
        MultiplicationQuestions()
    }
}

func Operation() {
    if addition_true == true {
        operation = "1"
    }else if subtract_true == true {
        operation = "2"
    }else  {
        operation = "3"
    }

    switch operation {
    case "1":
        finalanswer = n1 + n2
    case "2":
        finalanswer = n1 - n2
    case "3":
        finalanswer = n1 * n2
    default: break
    }
}

func AdditionQuestions() {
    n1 = arc4random_uniform(9)+1
    n2 = arc4random_uniform(9)+1
    n1_lbl.text = "\(n1)"
    n2_lbl.text = "\(n2)"
    symbol_lbl.text = "+"
    score_lbl.text = ""
    comment_lbl.text = ""
}

func SubtractionQuestions() {
    n1 = arc4random_uniform(9)+1
    n2 = arc4random_uniform(9)+1
    symbol_lbl.text = "-"
    if n2 > n1 {
        temp = n1
        n1 = n2
        n2 = temp
    }
    n1_lbl.text = "\(n1)"
    n2_lbl.text = "\(n2)"
}

func MultiplicationQuestions() {
    n1 = arc4random_uniform(9)+1
    n2 = arc4random_uniform(9)+1
    symbol_lbl.text = "×"
    n1_lbl.text = "\(n1)"
    n2_lbl.text = "\(n2)"
}

func EndQuiz() {
    if count > 3 {
        enter.hidden = true
        next.hidden = true
        back.hidden = false
        score_lbl.text = "Score: \(score)"
        comment_lbl.text = "Completed Quiz"
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func enter_entered(sender: AnyObject) {
    if answer_field.text != nil {
        enter_entered_true = true
        answer = UInt32(answer_field.text!)!
        count = count + 1
        Operation()
        if answer != finalanswer {
            comment_lbl.text = "Incorrect"
        } else {
            comment_lbl.text = "Correct"
            score = score + 1
        }
    } else {
        comment_lbl.text = "Enter a number!"
    }
    enter.hidden = true
    next.hidden = false
}

@IBAction func next_entered(sender: AnyObject) {
    if addition_true == true {
        AdditionQuestions()
        comment_lbl.text = ""
    }else if subtract_true == true {
        SubtractionQuestions()
        comment_lbl.text = ""
    }
    if multiply_true == true && addition_true == false && subtract_true == false{
        MultiplicationQuestions()
        comment_lbl.text = ""
    }
    enter.hidden = false
    next.hidden = true
    EndQuiz()
}
```

}

Comment: try printing the bool values of each transferred actions ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hit one of the buttons (Add, Subtract or Multiply) then the application immediately performs `prepareForSegue` before it performs the action associated with those buttons.  Therefore `addition_true`, `subtraction_true` and `multiplication_true` are all always false and the code falls through to the `else` clause which sets the multiplication option.

To get around this:

1. In the storyboard remove the segues from the three buttons.
2. Add a segue from the first view controller to the second one (control drag from the yellow circle at the top of the first view controller to the body of the second view controller).
3. Give the segue a name(highlight the segue and name it ("mainSegue" or something) in the Attributes Inspector)
4. In your code add the following line to the end of each of the three actions (`addition_enter`, etc.):

   `performSegueWithIdentifier("mainSegue", sender: self)`

This will ensure that the segue is called after the button actions have been performed.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Quiz_VC` class update **viewDidLoad()**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
back.hidden = true
next.hidden = true
if addition_true == true {
    AdditionQuestions()
}else if subtract_true == true {
    SubtractionQuestions()
}else if multiply_true == true{
    MultiplicationQuestions()
 }
}
```

and

```
func Operation() {
if addition_true == true {
    operation = "1"
}else if subtract_true == true {
    operation = "2"
}else if multiply_true == true  {
    operation = "3"
}

switch operation {
case "1":
    finalanswer = n1 + n2
case "2":
    finalanswer = n1 - n2
case "3":
    finalanswer = n1 * n2
default: break
}
}
```

also

```
 @IBAction func next_entered(sender: AnyObject) {
if addition_true == true {
    AdditionQuestions()
    comment_lbl.text = ""
}else if subtract_true == true {
    SubtractionQuestions()
    comment_lbl.text = ""
}else if multiply_true == true{
    MultiplicationQuestions()
    comment_lbl.text = ""
}else{
enter.hidden = false
next.hidden = true
EndQuiz()
  }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your @IBAction functions are not hooked up, or are not getting called because the button is linked to a segue.

This means that all of the Bools are false in prepareForSegue. And the logic in that function sets up the QuizVC for multiplication in that case (the last else clause does not have an if qualifier).

So, keep the segues in the storyboard. Populate the segue identifier string in the object inspector (the panel on the right in Xcode). Use, say, ADDITION_SEGUE, MULTIPLY_SEGUE, SUBTRACTION_SEGUE. You don't have to use caps and underscores, that's just my habit.

[image: Segue Identifier]

Then in prepareForSegue: you can tell which segue triggered the action. Set the properties on the QuizVC on the basis of that. Then you don't need those Bools at all in OptionVC.

In prepareForSegue:

```
if segue.identifier == "ADDITION_SEGUE" {
    destinationViewController...
}
```

How about also putting an enum into QuizVC rather than using the Bools:

```
enum QuizType {
    case Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication
}
```

That might make things a little easier in the long run. It kinda helps you manage state because the quiz type is only one of the three. Although, if the Bools work for you then fair enough.